# how to find out which webkit version for UiWebView user control?

Tags: macos, uiwebview

I am using XCode IDE for developing a web browser desktop app. The app is very simple and it uses UiWebView user control to display a web page content.

I am running into some issues with web page with specific version of web kit rendering engine that UiWebView user control uses. The UiWebView user controls load different web kit on different Mac OS (not sure how it was loaded).

The question I am having are:

- How do I specify the web kit rendering engine for the UiWebView user control? Can I overwrite the default web kit engine?
- If it is possible to use the my own UiWebView user control based on the version of web kit I choose.

Thank you in advance!

derek